# Outlook 365 - Multiple Gmail IMAP Accounts

Tags: memory, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I am setting up Microsoft Outlook (as part of Office 365) for a friend.

He has 6-7 Gmail accounts which we want to connect as IMAP. I remember trying this for him around 10-12 years ago but Outlook just couldn't handle it. It kept freezing and we couldn't get it to work.

My question is: Does anybody have any experience with such a scenario? Should Outlook now be stronger than 12 years ago? Or is this a RAM issue? If it is, how much RAM would I need for Outlook to be able to seamlessly handle 6-7 Gmail accounts via IMAP? The accounts are around 12 years old so there could be quite a few emails to download ("Keep Offline" as Outlook calls it). Ideally we would like to download everything but we could compromise on this; The main thing I need is for Outlook to work without any problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set just one or two Outlook Accounts to be active so that it is not trying to download a half dozen accounts at one time, that may help. I have 4 Accounts in my Outlook 2016 and I do as above and it works fine.

Comment: How do you make accounts active or inactive? Do you mean Send/receive Groups?

Comment: In Outlook, Main Ribbon, Send / Receive, Send / Receive Groups, and then go down to Define Send / Receive Groups .  In the Dialogue Window that comes up, click on Edit (at the side). Each of your accounts will show, and you can (top selection) include or not include (uncheck) from automatic send/receive.

Comment: Not a bad idea. However, I still want to know if it can work without having to do this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can turn the machine on, let it sync all accounts (download all) overnight so that when the user is syncing daily, there is not much of a load.  This will allow Outlook to work without a problem. Is there enough here for you to consider as an answer?

Comment: It should be okay to configure 6-7 gmail accounts on Outlook client at the same time. However, if you hava a lot of mails to be synced, this may cause Outlook freeze or it will take a long time to finish this. So it is suggested to set your accounts Keep mail offline for recent messages.